# How can I grab a mix of ints, floats, and strings using a pattern from a list?

Tags: python, list, lambda, scientific-notation

I have a list populated like so with the numeric values subject to being updated as well as the amount of entries in the list. It could have 1 entry, it could have 10.

```
# list is called m1[i]    
'probability': '0.00374'
'probability': '0'
'probability': '0.0978e-18'
```

When I print(m1) I get `'probability': '0.00374', 'probability': '0', 'probability': '0.0978e-18'`. I want to be able to take just the numbers `[0.00374, 0, 0.0978e-18]`. So a combination of Ints, Floats, and Scientific notation strings.

When it was just integers, I used this which worked fine but I am not sure how to change it to include the float or scientific notation.

```
CP_num = list(map(lambda sub:int(''.join([ele for ele in sub if ele.isnumeric()])), m1))
```

End result should output as `[0.00374, 0, 0.0978e-18]`. Bonus if it can convert scientific notation to a float in the process.

Comment: `'probability': '0.00374'` is not a valid list entry. You would either have a dict literal `{'probability': '0.00374'}` or a string `'probability: 0.00374'` Which is it?

Comment: each entry in that list is a string. From each entry, I was able to grab just the integers. Now I need to be able to grab floats and the scientific notations.

Answer (score 0):

`int()` and `float()` can be called on a string containing numbers directly. one of these should work:

```
CP_num = [map(lambda sub: float(sub), m1)]
CP_num = [map(lambda sub: float(num) for num in sub, m1)]
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without specifically stating the values in the list? How can I check `m1[i]` and take out just the numbers? Your code requires me to specify the numeric values beforehand. My `m1` list is `'probability': '0.00374', 'probability': '0', 'probability': '0.0978e-18'` which won't work with your code.

Comment: I'm having troubles inputting your values. It's not a list, rather looking like a dictionary. It can't be one though, because dicts require different keys. What type is this data you have?

Answer (score 0):

Given this list:

```
m=['probability: 0.00374',
'probability: 0',
'probability: 0.0978e-18']
```

You can do:

```
>>> [float(t[1]) for t in map(lambda s: s.split(':'), m)]
[0.00374, 0.0, 9.78e-20]
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Lambda so I cannot diagnose why it isn't working. I am getting `IndexError: list index out of range`. When I change the (,) to a space " ", I get a `ValueError: Could not convert string to float: "'0.00374'"`

I think the issue is that the layout of the string is `'probability': '0.00374'` but you are missing 2 single quotes (') in your example. I don't really know lambda to fix what you wrote.